# Boot issues - grub doesn't show up and Ubuntu is not a boot option either in UEFI boot order or Boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I would really appreciate some advice about my boot problems. I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS alongside Windows 10 on my Lenovo ThinkPad E14 (UEFI). I tried both automatic install and something else options, the result is the same. After restarting and removing the USB install stick, the computer boots to Windows.

I changed the setting of UEFI boot order, I checked that Secure boot is unabled, and also I tried to boot from the boot menu, there is no error message, but I guess that the computer fails to boot from the right part of memory and then continues in the boot order to Windows. I also tried to install Ubuntu while having Fast boot unabled in UEFI, it didn't help.

Also I tried to fix grub using boot repair, it reported a succesfull repair, but didn't solve the problem.
There is the URL from boot repair:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/c5nRw6vbsn

I also wanted to mention, that while booting from USB stick, some error message appears, see picture. (I have no idea whether it's relevant or not.)
[Picture of error while booting from USB stick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww5EW.jpg)